# How to use constexpr function template to re-write a very long switch-case efficiently?

Tags: c++, constexpr, function-templates

To easily re-write a big switch-case, I'm trying constexpr function template like this (it's only a simplified version with just cout):

```
#include <iostream>

template<int T>
constexpr void bigSwitchCase(const int idx)
{
    if (T == 1 && T == idx)
    {
        std::cout << 1 <<std::endl;
        return;
    }



    if (T == idx)
    {
        std::cout << T << std::endl;
    }
    else if (T > 1)
    {
        bigSwitchCase<T - 1>(idx);
    }

    return;
}

template<>
void bigSwitchCase<1>(const int idx)
{
    if (1== idx)
    {
        std::cout << 1 <<std::endl;
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    bigSwitchCase<64>(15);
    //bigSwitchCase<4096>(15);
    return 0;
}
```

but the problem is it is not producing as fast code as below version:

```
switch(idx)
{
case 1: std::cout << 1 << std::endl; break;
case 2: std::cout << 2 << std::endl; break;
...
case 4096: std::cout << 4096 << std::endl; break;
default:
}
```

because if-else parts in the constexpr function contains idx input which is not constexpr hence the if-else can not be made constxpr. But the switch-case elements are all cosntants.

So, the function produces a loop instead and checks against idx value, according to compiler-generated assembly codes. I need it to directly jump to the point that does the work instead of looping.

How to produce efficient code using only constexpr function templates (because real work includes plain arrays with compile-time sizes) with a run-time integer input (about ~4000 upper limit and 1 lower limit)?

Comment: Your example is not a good one, because the compiler may be clever enough to optimize it all to `if(idx >= 1 && idx <= 4096) { std::cout << idx << std::endl; break; }` and that is also more natural to write.

Comment: @user17732522 real world code has plain arrays with compile-time sizes and type casts & data copies which can not be optimized out.

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes I need just switch case (of up to 4096 lines) with a one-liner or similarly easy way. But in C++-way, not define macros.

Comment: Then just write out the whole switch. And this might be the one case where maybe (just maybe) I would use macros to write out the repeating code.

Comment: Or, how can I create a jump table (that jumps to template function) with constexpr & few lines of code? Can I have an array of functions each with different template parameter?

Comment: BTW, your constexpr `bigSwitchCase` has several flaws. You might `if constexpr` the recursion, and remove the 1 case (both specialization and regular case). `template<int T> constexpr void bigSwitchCase(int idx) { if (T == idx) { std::cout << T << std::endl; } else if constexpr (T > 1) { bigSwitchCase<T - 1>(idx); }`.

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you. This gets rid of looping right?

Comment: I didn't check generated code, but it is still linear, up to compiler to use jump table instead as optimization...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give the compiler a hint that you want a jump table instead of iteration through all cases by implementing it in that form yourself:

```
template<int I>
void doit()
{
    std::cout << I <<std::endl;
    return;
}

template<int N>
void bigSwitchCase(int idx) {
    static constexpr auto jumptable =
        []<int... Is>(std::integer_sequence<int, 0, Is...>){
            return std::array{doit<Is>...};
        }(std::make_integer_sequence<int, N+1>());
    if(idx >= 1 && idx <= N)
        jumptable[idx-1]();
}
```

Comment: Alright, I forgot about lambdas. Thank you.

Comment: Key here, is the array of function pointer, not the lambda to construct it ;-)